# Improving the SQL query processing performance of SUM in Oracle for a huge table

Tags: oracle, group-by, sum

I have a table containing about 1 billion rows with 50 columns
and I have a query like this but the processing time is extremely slow, or even no response, due to numbers of SUM functions included.  The query is used in direct database query in Oracle Analytics.

When all SUMs and GROUP BY are removed, it takes about 1 min to return result of 1 million rows.   With all the SUMs and GROUP BY added, the number of rows becomes about 5k.
As I need to use it in Excel for further analysis, I have to keep the output rows as less as possible to keep it small data size and have processing time not too slow.

```
Select Col_1,
       Col_2,
       ...,
       Col_10,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 1 and Col_6 = a then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 2 and Col_6 = b then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_2,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 6 and Col_6 = d then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_24
from table_a 
where col_1 = 1
      col_5 in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
      col_6 in (a,b,c,d)
Group by Col_1, Col_2,...,Col_10
```

I have tried to get the query plan with EXPLAIN or add index by CREATE INDEX but unfortunately they are both not supported. it is confirmed that SELECT statement or WITH clause can be used in the system. And I have no other application or system which can access the same database that I need.
What can I do to optimise the performance?

Comment: Sql server seems like a wrong tag for your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use indexes for this. Here's a few things to check:

1. Are you using parallelism (PQ)? With a billion rows, you're going to want a healthy # of PX slaves. Assuming your database server has sufficient CPU, try with this hint:

`SELECT /*+ parallel(16) */ col_1, ....`

2. Make sure you are actually getting the parallel slaves requested. Check `gv$session` and see if you have twice the # of P0** processes as the DOP requested. If not, ask your DBA if you are being downgraded for some reason. Just because you get a parallel plan doesn't mean you'll get the actual parallel slaves you want at exec time.
3. Check the explain plan and make sure it's doing a *full table scan*. You *don't* want indexes being used here. If you *do* see an index being used, force a full scan with a hint: `SELECT /*+ parallel(16) full(table_a) */`
4. If the table is partitioned, can you add a predicate on the partitioning key (see `all_part_key_columns`) to prune partitions you don't need?
5. Ask your DBA or if you can query yourself `v$pgastat` and check the value for `global memory bound`. Is it less than 1G? If so, have your DBA raise the `pga_aggregate_target` (and limit, too, if set and not high enough) until the global memory bound shows its maximum possible value of 1G. This will ensure you get as much memory as you need allocated to those aggregations before using temp space in a workarea. Just be sure you have enough free memory or OS file cache (freeable) on the database host(s). What this does is reduce the amount of time spent on I/O to the temporary tablespace and allow the hash or sort aggregations to take place in physical memory. Or rather, allow more of it to happen in memory than otherwise would. Chances are with 1 billion rows something will spill to disk no matter what, but you want to be as generous as you can be.
6. Finally, if none of the above works for you, if you have EE and Diagnostics and Tuning option then generate a SQL Monitor report for your sql_id and share it with us:

   ```
   SELECT dbms_sql_monitor.report_sql_monitor(sql_id => '82nqt262ycyng', -- replace with your sql_id
                                              report_level => 'ALL') 
     FROM dual;
   ```

Comment: Thanks very much for your advices. I tried to add  /*+ parallel(16) */ but the performance 
 didn't get better. and even it is much slower when I remove all SUM and add /*+ parallel(16) */.

Comment: I wonder if I should partition into small data set for each SUM (i.e. 24 pieces with about ~40k rows each) and then use JOIN to get the final result?

Comment: @LaurenMickey, no, splitting it up like that won't help. Proper tuning requires looking at the wait profile of your SQL execution and determining what wait event consumed the most time at what step in the execution plan. Only then can a targeted response be attempted. Can you get a SQL Monitor? Also the parallelism was specifically designed for the GROUP BY and SUM operations. It wouldn't be appropriate for a straight select (and you can't really gauge performance of a straight select since you'd be seeing only the response time for the first row fetched, not throughput of the entire dataset).

Answer (score 0):

1 thing I can suggest you is to use the between operator instead of In predicate in your query. This will definitely enhanced the performance of the query -

```
Select Col_1,
       Col_2,
       ...,
       Col_10,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 1 and Col_6 = a then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_1,
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 2 and Col_6 = b then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_2,
       ...
       SUM(CASE WHEN col_5 = 6 and Col_6 = d then AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) as AMT_24
from table_a 
where col_1 = 1
  AND col_5 BETWEEN 1 AND 6
  AND col_6 BETWEEN a AND d
Group by Col_1, Col_2,...,Col_10
```

Comment: Why would the BETWEEN operator be faster than the IN operator?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Ankit. 
But there are 10 to 15 possible values in each of the columns and I only need 4-6 of them to filter each time.   
Sometime they are not consecutive. I think BETWEEN may not be appropriate in this case